# react datetimepicker with meteor

Tags: reactjs, meteor, datetimepicker

I am a newbie to meteor and react , sorry if this is a silly question.

I am trying to put a react datetimepicker in my meteor project without success.

below is the project structure  ( same as the todo app in meteor's official guide)

```
imports

   -ui


      -App.jsx

      -Example.jsx
```

code in Example.jsx   (which I copied from the Controlled Component example in http://dev.quri.com/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker/]1

```
import React from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import moment from 'moment';

import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

// CSS Modules, react-datepicker-cssmodules.css
// import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker-cssmodules.css';

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      startDate: moment()
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(date) {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <DatePicker
        selected={this.state.startDate}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
    />;
  }
}
```

code in App.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Example from './Example.jsx';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import moment from 'moment';



export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
            <h1> Time selecting </h1>
            <DatePicker selected={this.state.date} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
    )
    };
```

}

My app can run and print the line "Time selecting" before I tried to add the datetimepicker and put the line

```
<DatePicker selected={this.state.date} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

in App.jsx

How can I use the datetimepicker correctly?

---

Now I deleted the Example.jsx file and changed the file in App.jsx  to

```
import React from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import moment from 'moment';

export default class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          date: "1990-06-05",
          format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
          inputFormat: "DD/MM/YYYY",
          mode: "date"
        };

         this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      }

      handleChange(date) {
        this.setState({
            startDate: date
        });
     }

      render() {

    return (
                <div className="container">
                   <h1> Time selecting </h1>
                   <DatePicker selected={this.state.startDate} 
                                         onChange = {this.handleChange} />
                </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

but the browser is still showing nothing.

Comment: Are this.state.date and this.handleChange undefined in your example?

Comment: any error in the console?

Comment: @larrydahooster I simply copied the code . It might be undefined.           
 Uh.... So how do I defined it if  I want a datetimepicker showed on my browser (newbie here, sorry)

Comment: @abdul  There is no error in the console. The browser just became a white screen and showed nothing after I paste the code    '<DatePicker selected={this.state.date} onChange={this.handleChange} />'                              Before I paste that line, the browser is printing "Time selecting"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably just copied only the `<DatePicker>` part you should also include the handleChange call back function and the initial state like below.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
    import moment from 'moment';

   class Application extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {date: moment()};
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      }

      handleChange(date) {
        this.setState({
            startDate: date
        });
     }


  render() {
    return <div className="container">
                   <h1> Time selecting </h1>
                   <DatePicker selected={this.state.date}
                    onChange={this.dateChanged} />
                </div>
  }
}
```

here is the [codepen for react-datepicker demo.](https://codepen.io/jochenberger/pen/xRpQOK)

Comment: The browser still remain a white screen. In case I did something wrong, I'll put my changes in my initial question.

Comment: you will need to install the imported packages. use `npm install react-datepicker --save`  to install react date picker for more details check out the following links https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker and https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment for Moment js.

Comment: I did and tried installed it again . But it's still not working.